# (Предположительно) не работает .value в js

Tags: javascript, html

Месяц в Js. Суть задания - есть поле ввода и кнопка. Когда нажимаешь на кнопку генерируется рандомный цвет и ставится на задний фон. Когда вписываешь red/blue/green в поле ввода то задний фон должен быть оттенком красного/синего/зеленого. Вот то что у меня вышло:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">            
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
 <body>
  <input type="text" value="Поле ввода" id="col">
  <button id="but">я кнопка</button>
  <script>
  'use strict'
      
  function randInt(min, max){
      return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
  }
  
  function randomColor(a){
      if (a="red"){
          let a = randInt(0, 255)+80;
          let b = randInt(0, 255);  
          let c = randInt(0, 255);
          return (a, b, c)
      }
      if (a="blue"){
          let a = randInt(0, 255);
          let b = randInt(0, 255)+80;  
          let c = randInt(0, 255);
          return (a, b, c)
          console.log("blue")
      }
      if (a="green"){
          let a = randInt(0, 255);
          let b = randInt(0, 255);  
          let c = randInt(0, 255)+80;
          return (a, b, c)
      }
      
  }
        
  function decToHex(n) {
   return n.toString(16);
  }
  

  
 but.addEventListener("click", function(e){
     let first = decToHex(randomColor(col.value));    
     let second = decToHex(randomColor(col.value)); 
     let third = decToHex(randomColor(col.value));
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#"+first+second+third;
     
 });
 </script>
</body>
```

Рандомный цвет работает, а поле ввода не работает. if не активируется( в консоль ничего не выводиться в консоль логе) так что я думаю что проблема в том как я использую .value, но я без понятия, помогите

Comment: равенство если что это `==` а не `=`. И в целом вызывает сомнения целесообразность того, что во всех ветках ифов у вас одинаковый код. и откуда `col` берется?

Comment: вы не обьявили col
JS к сожалению ненастолько умен как хотелось бы let col = document.querySelector("#col")

Comment: `col` это айдишник поля ввода в которое те цвета и вводятся. Я новичек, не сразу додумался в одну строчку вписать '-'